# Why am I getting 0 instead of 0.5 here?

Tags: c++, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division in C++ not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101084/division-in-c-not-working-as-expected)

Turns out my program has been returning wrong results, so I decided to break the code into little pieces. After setting breakpoint, turns out that...

```
double test3 = ((2 - 1) / 2);
```

...equals 0 according to C++ compiler. I have no idea why. Can someone explain it to me?

I'm using MS Visual Studio Premium 2012

Comment: rounding to int during dividion... just do double test3 = ((2.0 - 1.0))/2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are doing integer division. `1/2` is `0`, which is then converted to `double`, yielding `0.`. If you want floating point division, try making one of the arguments of the division a floating point number:

```
double test3 = (2.0-1)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the numbers you used on the right hand side are all integers: (i.e.: the expression `(2-1)/2` evaluates to `0` as `(int)1/(int)2` evaluates to `0` since the whole thing is an integer.

Change it to:

```
double test3 = ((2 - 1) / 2.0);
```

And the expression is then `(int)1/(double)2`, which will evaluate to a double, and thus `0.5`

Answer (score 1):

When only integers are involved in an expression, you will only get integer arithmetic. If you want to have floating point arithmetic, you need to involve a floating point expression at some point, e.g.

```
double test3 = ((2 - 1) / 2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try making your numbers double, (2.-1.)/2.;