# I keep getting 1 1 1 1 1 outputted when I am trying to show the float values of 1, 1/2, 1/3..... 1/n. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWSuk.jpg)

I keep getting 1 1 1 1 1 outputted when I am trying to show the float values of 1, 1/2, 1/3..... 1/n. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as text. There's no easy way to try code in an image ourselves, nor can we we copy it into our answers, and it won't show up in future Google searches. See: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: Sounds like you're using `int` when you should be using `double`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division in C++ not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101084/division-in-c-not-working-as-expected) or [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Although `sum` is of float type, `i` is not. By doing `1/i` you are doing `int/int` division which evidently rounds down.

What's happening is this: `1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n` = `1 + 0 + ... + 0` = 1.

You can resolve this by casting or changing the type of `i`. 
A simple solution could be:

```
sum = sum + ((float)1 / i);
```

Or even:

```
sum = sum + (1.0/i);
```